# Check account balance

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I installed a node on the pc with the parameters `geth --rpc --rpcaddr localhost --rpcport 8545` and I want to check the account balance:

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
const address = '0xbdfd7125408363bfa36b8e83753b53dd695eef24' 
web3.eth.getBalance(address, (err, wei) => {
  console.log(balance = web3.utils.fromWei(wei, 'ether'))
})
```

but the balance is always 0, although there are funds there, what’s the problem?

Comment: Is geth connected to mainnet? Has it finished syncing?

Comment: @Ismael How to check which network geth is connected to? Get attach shows  currentBlock: 9047446,
 highestBlock: 9047561,
 knownStates: 75526676,
 pulledStates: 75522784,
 startingBlock: 9047228

Comment: Default is mainnet. It seems your node hasn't finished syncing. You cannot use it until it has synced.

Comment: @Ismael Geth parameters: geth --rpc --rpcaddr localhost --rpcport 8545 The problem is that geth cannot be fully synchronized, 1 in 1, it always lags a few blocks

Comment: full node on a normal pc rarely works,  try fast sync